# Return Enum Constant based on an incoming String Value

Tags: c#

I'm going to grab the enum value from a querystring.

For instance lets say I have this enum:

```
Enum MyEnum
{
    Test1,
    Test2,
    Test3
}
```

I'm going to grab the value from an incoming querystring, so:

```
string myEnumStringValue = Request["somevar"];
```

myEnumStringValue could be "0", "1", "2"

I need to get back the actual Enum Constant based on that string value.

I could go and create a method that takes in the string and then perform a case statement

```
case "0":
    return MyEnum.Test1;
    break;
```

but there's got to be an easier or more slick way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx), which can convert names or values to the correct enum value.

Once you have that, cast the result to `MyEnum` and call `ToString()` to get the name of the constant.

```
return ((MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), Request["somevar"])).ToString();
```

Comment: Indeed, and Enum.Parse handles that. (Though I may not have fleshed out my answer when you posted that!)

Comment: Yea, not trying to get the name of the constant to string..but the constant itself

Comment: so I just need the (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), Request["somevar"].  Thanks did not know about the parse yet.

Answer (score 2):

There is built-in functionality for this task:

`MyEnum convertedEnum = (MyEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), myEnumStringValue);`

Comment: Hah, it seems Enum.Parse handles it:) Learned something new:)

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the string to get its integer value, cast the value to the `Enum` type, then get the enum value's name, like this:

```
string myEnumStringValue = ((MyEnum)int.Parse(Request["somevar"])).ToString();
```

**EDIT**: Or, you can simply call `Enum.Parse`.  However, this should be a little bit faster.

Comment: Is there a benefit to using the Enum.Parse() vs. int.Parse()?  Example:  ((MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), Request["somevar"])).ToString();

Comment: @Zacharay: `int.Parse` is a little faster.